# Phrasal verbs for stop working at the end of the day

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I want to ask my friend when she will leave the office at the end of the day.
I have found two phrasal verbs for this purpose.
**Knock off** and **get off**

> What time do you knock off work?
>   What time do you get off work?

What is the difference between these two phrasal verbs in expressing the meaning "leave the office"?
Is there any other phrasal verbs to express this meaning?

Comment: What time do you check out [from office]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second phrase is more polite.

The first one is more casual: chummy; friendly. Requires a level of intimacy above absolute zero between the two parties.

With an even higher level of intimacy, phrases such as "At what time do you stop being a lackey of capitalism?" become permissible.